# Unbound breakpoint in Visual Studio Code

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, debugging, breakpoints

I have some open source code that I am trying to debug. The client side is written in TypeScript. While the server part can be debugged just fine, the client cannot. The client gets invoked, and the debug session is running but when trying to set a breakpoint, I'm getting
"unbound breakpoint" when running:

[image]

I'm not using any *launch.json* for debugging.

This is the log:

```
suroi-master/client
$ pnpm run dev
Debugger attached.
 WARN  Unsupported engine: wanted: {"node":">=18.8.0"} (current: {"node":"v18.4.0","pnpm":"8.6.12"})

> @suroi/client@ dev C:\dev\my\js\io\suroi-master\client
> webpack serve --config ./webpack/webpack.dev.ts

Debugger attached.
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Project is running at:
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Loopback: http://localhost:3000/
<i> [webpack-dev-server] On Your Network (IPv4): http://10.100.102.13:3000/
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Content not from webpack is served from 'C:\dev\my\js\io\suroi-master\client\public' directory
<i> [webpack-dev-server] 404s will fallback to '/index.html'
92% sealing asset processing webpack-spritesheet-plugin
(process:8180): Pango-WARNING **: 14:29:22.526: couldn't load font "Inter Bold Not-Rotated 21.15625", falling back to "Sans Bold Not-Rotated 21.15625", expect ugly output.

(process:8180): Pango-WARNING **: 14:29:22.566: couldn't load font "Sans Serif Not-Rotated 12.19921875", falling back to "Sans Not-Rotated 12.19921875", expect ugly output.
assets by info 9.51 MiB [immutable]
  assets by chunk 986 KiB (auxiliary name: app) 15 assets
  assets by path js/*.js 8.37 MiB 7 assets
  assets by path css/*.css 181 KiB 4 assets
assets by path img/atlases/ 3.62 MiB
  assets by status 3.56 MiB [big] 2 assets
  assets by path img/atlases/*.json 63.1 KiB 2 assets
assets by path ./ 11.7 KiB
  asset ./changelog/index.html 5.73 KiB [emitted]
  asset ./rules/index.html 2.38 KiB [emitted]
  asset ./news/index.html 2.33 KiB [emitted]
  asset ./leaderboard/index.html 1.25 KiB [emitted]
asset index.html 16.8 KiB [emitted]
Entrypoint app [big] 8.38 MiB (11.2 MiB) = js/manifest.9d1e2c3a.js 48.3 KiB js/vendor.1affff20.js 7.95 MiB css/app.00dca8df.css 47.4 KiB js/app.2bdad6f3.js 345 KiB 19 auxiliary assets
Entrypoint changelog [big] 8 MiB (9.66 MiB) = js/manifest.9d1e2c3a.js 48.3 KiB js/vendor.1affff20.js 7.95 MiB css/changelog.8eeed98b.css 1.15 KiB js/changelog.7934ec08.js 2.03 KiB 4 auxiliary assets
Entrypoint leaderboard [big] 8 MiB (9.66 MiB) = js/manifest.9d1e2c3a.js 48.3 KiB js/vendor.1affff20.js 7.95 MiB js/leaderboard.9a620d14.js 999 bytes 2 auxiliary assets
Entrypoint news [big] 8.08 MiB (10.7 MiB) = js/manifest.9d1e2c3a.js 48.3 KiB js/vendor.1affff20.js 7.95 MiB css/news.65c509c0.css 66.2 KiB js/news.2b6eeb13.js 19.4 KiB 19 auxiliary assets
Entrypoint rules [big] 8.07 MiB (10.7 MiB) = js/manifest.9d1e2c3a.js 48.3 KiB js/vendor.1affff20.js 7.95 MiB css/rules.65c509c0.css 66.2 KiB js/rules.0c990a45.js 8.97 KiB 19 auxiliary assets
runtime modules 72.2 KiB 41 modules
orphan modules 178 KiB (javascript) 986 KiB (asset) [orphan] 22 modules
javascript modules 8.12 MiB
  modules by path ../ 7.92 MiB
    modules by path ../node_modules/.pnpm/ 7.81 MiB 85 modules
    modules by path ../common/src/ 117 KiB 25 modules
  modules by path ./src/ 204 KiB
    modules by path ./src/scripts/ 200 KiB 40 modules
    modules by path ./src/*.ts 3.36 KiB 5 modules
    modules by path ./src/scss/pages/*.scss 1.16 KiB 3 modules
css modules 66.8 KiB
  css ../node_modules/.pnpm/css-loader@6.8.1_webpack@5.88.2/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!../node_modules/.pnpm/postcss-loader@7.3.3_postcss@8.4.27_webpack@5.88.2/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js!../node_modules/.pnpm/sass-loader@13.3.2_sass@1.64.2_webpack@5.88.2/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/scss/pages/client.scss 47.7 KiB [built] [code generated]
  css ../node_modules/.pnpm/css-loader@6.8.1_webpack@5.88.2/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!../node_modules/.pnpm/postcss-loader@7.3.3_postcss@8.4.27_webpack@5.88.2/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js!../node_modules/.pnpm/sass-loader@13.3.2_sass@1.64.2_webpack@5.88.2/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/scss/pages/changelog.scss 57 bytes [built] [code generated]
  css ../node_modules/.pnpm/css-loader@6.8.1_webpack@5.88.2/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!../node_modules/.pnpm/postcss-loader@7.3.3_postcss@8.4.27_webpack@5.88.2/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js!../node_modules/.pnpm/sass-loader@13.3.2_sass@1.64.2_webpack@5.88.2/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/scss/pages/news.scss 19 KiB [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.88.2 compiled successfully in 12303 ms
```